# Accessing an object from another module when the class is also in a different module?

Tags: python, class, module

Hello i'm still kinda new to object oriented programming as well as python and i'm a little stuck.

I have three files one file contains a class, another file accesses this class and a third file that needs to access the object created in the main file.

class file

```
#Class.py
class myclass:
   def method(self, value)
   return value
```

Main File

```
#Main file

import Class

Myobj = Class.myclass
```

file 3.

```
#file 3
x= 10
#I need to access the output of myobj.method(x) from file3 but I cannot import main 
#into file 3
```

In my program the main file will initialize the class (the class will read in a file and assigns the contents of the file to arrays when it is initialized).

the class file also preforms a mathematical operation (the method function in the class file) but this function is dependent on a value that is calculated in file 3.

So I need the value that myobj.method(x) will output in file 3, the value of x will change as the program runs so I will end up with several outputs from myobj.method(x)

The problem is the main file can be any name the user chooses, so I cant simply import main into file 3.

Comment: BTW, in my answer I'll stick to the names you used, but you may want to check out the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (PEP 8); it sets out guidelines on how to name things; modules are generally lowercased, class names use CamelCase.

Answer (score 5):

You can only do that if you *store* the output of `myobj.method(3)` first:

```
#Main file

import Class

myobj = Class.myclass()
output = myobj.method(3)
```

Now you can refer to `Main.output` after importing `Main`.

`print` doesn't store anything; all it does is turn the expressions that follow it into strings and write those strings to the standard output. Technically, you could try and replace `sys.stdout`, but then you'd only capture strings, not actual original values.

It sounds, however, as if you want to expose some kind of API to a 3rd party that will import both `Class` and your 3rd module. In that case, have the user of your API call a hook method in your 3rd library instead, or have it set a value:

```
import thirdmodule

thirdmodule.configure(myobj.method(3))
```

This neatly avoids circular imports too.

Another option is for `Class` to be made responsible for updating `thirdmodule`; at the end of `myclass.method()` add code to update `thirdmodule`:

```
#Class.py

import thirdmodule

class myclass:
    def method(self, arg):
         # Do your thing
         retval = some_calculation()

         thirdmodule.x = retval

         return retval
```

Comment: Problem is the user is the one who dictates what main will be called (i just used main here as an example) so is it possible to access myobj.method(3) without importing main into file 3?

I will import file 3 into main though.

Comment: @JohnTracey: You should not do circular imports. No, you cannot do that. Have the user call a method in your module instead. Or set an attribute in your module, etc.

Comment: Could you give me an example please of what you mean?

Comment: So what does .configure actually do?

Also in this case the value fed into myobj.method is a constant but I acthully file3 will output the value that is needed to be fed to myobj.method, how could I do this?

Comment: @JohnTracey: It is a function that `thirdmodule` would have to define. Why don't you update your question and tell is a little more as to what you are trying to do at all?

Comment: I might be wrong but doesn't your second solution mean that im simply updated the value of x rather than passing it as argument for myclass.method ?

You see I need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Your question is getting more muddled by the minute. `Class` can also *read* `x` grom `thirdmodule`.

Comment: Well I didn't think it would be as complicated as this and I did say in my edit that the mathematical function is dependent on x.

Right so if I read x from ThirdModule will it be in the same object that was created in main? Since I need to access the data when the class was initialized

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you're going to want to change your method definition like so:

```
def method(self, value):
    return value
```

Secondly, in your main file, let's assume it's called mainfile.py, you'll have to **assign** the value of `myobj.method(3)` to some variable. Let's call it `val`.

So your print line then becomes `a = myobj.method(3)`

Then, in your third file, you import your main file with an `import mainfile`. The `.py` extension is unnecessary. Past that, it's simple: your output is stored in the variable `mainfile.val`; you can access that.

Oh, also, in your main file, you've called your object `Myobj` first and then `myobj`, you may want to fix that.